# In ADF, are copy data activities wrapped in transactions?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-data-factory

I have a copy data activity that is moving data from a managed instance to a sql database. The flow of the process is:

- truncate a staging table on the sql database as a distinct activity
- call a stored procedure as a source in the copy activity
- land the data in the staging table on the sql database in the copy activity

There is a retry on the copy activity because we are having transient issues, and this is the guidance from Microsoft to handle these errors.

My question(s) then is - if the data is being copied to the staging table, and this is interrupted by a transient error, and then the retry is called, will the staging table be empty because a transaction is rolled back? Or will some of the data from the first try still be there, and then I will end up with duplicate data?

I have spent some time digging around, including https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#resume-from-last-failed-run, but cannot find anything to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

no, you have to build something like this for rollbacking:

[image]